# webpack config how to change plugins depending on environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Hi is it possible to make plugins in webpack configuration depending on environement?

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: 'src/www/'}
        ])
        // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        // new CompressionPlugin({
        //     algorithm: 'gzip',
        //     test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/
        // }),
        // new UglifyJsPlugin({
        //     test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i
        // })
    ]
```

The commented ones should only be used if I bundle it with `NODE_ENV=production`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create multi webpack config files, one for each environment you want to support.
https://gist.github.com/Pepeye/8228bd468d5bc065fb33

Comment: You can have a config file for each environment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on your requirements, add the plugins if the env is production else return false, and filter the array based on the Boolean, but the preferred way is to create a different file for the different env, it will be much cleaner approach.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: 'src/www/'}
        ])
        NODE_ENV==='production' ? new BundleAnalyzerPlugin() : false,
        NODE_ENV==='production' ? new CompressionPlugin({
             algorithm: 'gzip',
             test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/
        }) : false,
        NODE_ENV==='production' ?  new UglifyJsPlugin({
             test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i
        }) : false
 ].filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: when I run this I got error `NODE_ENV is not defined`

Comment: in your package.json there should be script which sets the NODE_ENV variable something like this "scripts": {
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js",
}

Comment: for sure I run it like this: `"build": "node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=production NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 webpack --config webpack.config.js --optimize-minimize --optimize-dedupe",` but terminal returns NODE_ENV not defined

Comment: replace the NODE_ENV check with process.env.NODE_ENV, like process.env.NODE_ENV==='production' ? new BundleAnalyzerPlugin() : false,

Comment: Great! It works for me, but the answer is not full. You should have in your package.json in the "scripts" section something like this `"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --hide-modules --progress"`. And in your `webpack.config.json` something like this `const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"` or just use `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Answer (score 2):

Using your example I would prefer something like this:

```js
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'src/www/'}
    ])
    NODE_ENV === 'production' && new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    NODE_ENV === 'production' && new CompressionPlugin({
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/
    }),
    NODE_ENV === 'production' && new UglifyJsPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i
    })
].filter(n => n)
```

or if you prefer ES5:

```js
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'src/www/'}
    ])
    NODE_ENV === 'production' && new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    NODE_ENV === 'production' && new CompressionPlugin({
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/
    }),
    NODE_ENV === 'production' && new UglifyJsPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i
    })
].filter(function (plugin) { return plugin; })
```

---

What this snippet does is adding a conditional (`NODE_ENV === 'production'`) to the array, which is simply telling the JS compiler to either write `false` or the right-hand code to the array. The `filter` function on the other hand is only saying, filter out stuff that is `false` or false-ish.

Let's assume we are on `NODE_ENV = 'development'`, our plugins would look like this:

```
[HotModuleReplacementPlugin, NamedModulesPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin, CopyWebpackPlugin, false, false, false].filter(...)
```

after the filter has made it's job, we are having this one:

```
[HotModuleReplacementPlugin, NamedModulesPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin, CopyWebpackPlugin]
```

---

If we now assume we are on `NODE_ENV = 'production'`, our plugins would look like this:

```
[HotModuleReplacementPlugin, NamedModulesPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin, CopyWebpackPlugin, BundleAnalyzerPlugin, CompressionPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin].filter(...)
```

after the filter has made it's job, we are having this one:

```
[HotModuleReplacementPlugin, NamedModulesPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin, CopyWebpackPlugin, BundleAnalyzerPlugin, CompressionPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have A file config per environment

```
webpack
├── base.config.js
└── prod.config.js
```

```js
// base.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
      'NODE_ENV',
    ]),
  ],
};
```

```js
// prod.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const baseConfig = require('./base.config.js');

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
  ....
  plugins: [
    // Minify JS
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: false,
      compress: true,
    })
  ],
});
```

then in your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack/dev.config.js"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how i use plugin only in production

```
// Load this plugin only when running webpack in a production environment
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  module.exports.plugins.push(
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      analyzerPort: 4000
    }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with rest operator for cleaner look:

```js
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const plugins = isDev ? [
  new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
] : [
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    openAnalyzer: process.env.OPEN_ANALYZER === 'true',
  }),
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
    NODE_ENV: 'production',
    DEBUG_PROD: false,
    START_MINIMIZED: false,
  }),
]
```

Then inside the configuration file:

```js
plugins: [
     ...plugins,
     new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: 'source',
          to: 'destination',
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
```

Now we don't need those nasty comparisons.